# EF don't include rows where the field deleted at got a value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, include, where-clause

I use in my project the entity framework (EF) and in each table I got the columns, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, DeletedAt.

My data model looks like this:

Match contains a division, childmatches (replica of the match model), matchteams.

Matchteams can have scores.

I created a IQueryable and I included there all the relations:

```
private IQueryable<Models.Entities.Match> MatchWithEntities(CompetitionContext db)
   {
        return db.Matches.Include(x => x.Division)
                          .Include(x => x.ChildMatches)
                          .Include(x => x.ChildMatches.Select(y => y.Division))
                          .Include(x => x.ChildMatches.Select(y => y.MatchTeams))
                          .Include(x => x.ChildMatches.Select(y => y.MatchTeams.Select(z => z.Team)))
                          .Include(x => x.ChildMatches.Select(y => y.MatchTeams.Select(z => z.Team.Club)))
                          .Include(x => x.ChildMatches.Select(y => y.MatchTeams.Select(z => z.TeamMembers)))
                          .Include(x => x.ChildMatches.Select(y => y.MatchTeams.Select(z => z.TeamMembers.Select(a => a.Member))))
                          .Include(x => x.ChildMatches.Select(y => y.MatchTeams.Select(z => z.TeamMembers.Select(a => a.Member.Club))))
                          .Include(x => x.ChildMatches.Select(y => y.MatchTeams.Select(z => z.Scores)))
                          .Include(x => x.MatchTeams)
                          .Include(x => x.MatchTeams.Select(y => y.Team))
                          .Include(x => x.MatchTeams.Select(y => y.Team).Select(z => z.Club))
                          .Include(x => x.MatchTeams.Select(y => y.TeamMembers))
                          .Include(x => x.MatchTeams.Select(y => y.TeamMembers.Select(z => z.Member)))
                          .Include(x => x.MatchTeams.Select(y => y.TeamMembers.Select(z => z.Member.Club)))
                          .Include(x => x.MatchTeams.Select(y => y.Scores))
                          .Where(
                                x => !x.DeletedAt.HasValue &&
                                x.MatchTeams.Any(y => !y.Scores.Any() || y.Scores.Any(z => !z.DeletedAt.HasValue))
                          ).OrderBy(x => x.StartAt);
    }
```

Here is the code where I get the data:

```
 public async Task<Models.Entities.Match> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new CompetitionContext())
        {
            return await MatchWithEntities(db).FirstAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

In the where I added the sentence: 
x.MatchTeams.Any(y => !y.Scores.Any() || y.Scores.Any(z => !z.DeletedAt.HasValue))

So a matchteam can have 0 scores or have scores but then I want only the scores where the field DeletedAt don't have a value so NULL.

But I still get back rows with DeletedAt got a value.

Hope someone can help me with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: try z.DeletedAt == null

Comment: @SaadAlothman Thanks for your reply I also tried that but still I get back those rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue but I just have the same issue.
Turn out that you can use `.IgnoreQueryFilters()` on your request. It would enable the fact that LinQ use a filter including the `.Where(r => deletedAt == null)` on every request.

```
db.Matches.IgnoreQueryFilters().Include(x => x.Division) ...
```